Flex and Bison not accepting input file
I am writing a Flex & Bison program for a class, and I feel that I am almost done.  However, when I try to run the program with an input file, it simply refuses to read it and has me input lines instead.
I have two code files:tp2.l(for Flex) and tp2.y (for Bison).  Their code is below.
tp2.l (Flex code)
%option noyywrap

%{
  //#include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  //#include <string.h>
  #include "tp2.tab.h"
  
  int yylex();
%}

%%

[0-9]+ { printf("%s, integer\n", yytext); yylval.numValue = atoi(yytext); return NUM; }

"+" { printf("%s, operator\n", yytext); return ADD; }
"-" { printf("%s, operator\n", yytext); return SUB; }
"*" { printf("%s, operator\n", yytext); return MUL; }
"/" { printf("%s, operator\n", yytext); return DIV; }
"^" { printf("%s, operator\n", yytext); return POW; }
"=" { printf("equal sign\n"); return EQUAL; }

[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* { strcpy(yylval.stringValue, yytext); printf("%s, variable\n", yytext); return VAR; }

[ \t] {}
"\n"  { printf("Newline\n"); yylval.charValue = yytext[0]; return ENDL; }
. { printf("Unknown\n"); return ERR; }

%%

tp2.y (Bison code)
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    const int ADDITION = 0;
    const int SUBTRACTION = 1;
    const int MULTIPLICATION = 2;
    const int DIVISION = 3;
    const int POWER = 4;

    // Node types
    const int INSTRUCTION = 0;
    const int VALUE = 1;
    const int VARIABLE = 2;

    int yyerror(const char *s);
    extern int yylex();
    extern int yyparse();
    extern FILE *yyin;

    // A parse tree node.  Has either a value, instruction, or variable name. 
    struct ParseNode {
        int type;

        int value; // Holds numerical value..
        char varName[255]; // Holds variable name.
        char symbol;    // Mathematical symbol

        // Branch nodes, can be NULL.
        struct ParseNode* left;
        struct ParseNode* right;
    };

    // Node creation functions.
    // These create & return a node.  If the ROOT is NULL, set the root to the node you created.

    // Creates & returns an instruction node.
    struct ParseNode *createInstructionNode(char op, struct ParseNode* left, struct ParseNode* right)
    {
        struct ParseNode* node = (struct ParseNode* )malloc(sizeof(struct ParseNode));
        
        //struct ParseNode node;
        node->type = INSTRUCTION;
        node->symbol = op;
        node->left = left;
        node->right = right;

        return node;
    }

    // Creates & returns a value node.
    struct ParseNode *createValueNode(int value, struct ParseNode* left, struct ParseNode* right)
    {
        struct ParseNode* node = (struct ParseNode* )malloc(sizeof(struct ParseNode));
        node->type = VALUE;
        node->value = value;
        node->left = left;
        node->right = right;
        
        return node;
    }

    // Creates & returns a variable node.
    struct ParseNode *createVariableNode(char *varName, struct ParseNode* left, struct ParseNode* right)
    {
        struct ParseNode* node = (struct ParseNode* )malloc(sizeof(struct ParseNode));
        node->type = VARIABLE;
        node->left = left;
        node->right = right;
        strcpy(varName, node->varName);

        return node;
    }

    // Calculate the depth of a tree node.
    int treeDepth(struct ParseNode *root)
    {
        if(root == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int left_depth = treeDepth(root->left);
            int right_depth = treeDepth(root->right);

            if(left_depth > right_depth)
                return left_depth;
            return right_depth;
        }
    }

    // Print a NULL spot in the tree.
    void printNull(int depth, int index)
    {
        if(depth > 0)
        {
            printNull(depth-1, (index*2));
            printNull(depth-1, (index*2) + 1);
        }
        printf("%d %d \n", depth, index);
    }

    void printNode(struct ParseNode* root, int depth, int index)
    {
        // Recurse to lower nodes.
        if(depth > 0)
        {
            if(root->left == NULL)
                printNull(depth-1, (index*2));
            else
                printNode(root->left, depth-1, (index * 2));

            if(root->right == NULL)
                printNull(depth-1, (index*2) + 1);
            else
                printNode(root->right, depth-1, (index * 2) + 1);
        }
        
        // Print the contents of the node.
        printf("%d %d ", depth, index);
        if(root == NULL)
        {
            printf("_");
            return;
        }
        switch(root->type)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("%c", root->symbol);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("%d", root->value);
                break;
            default:
                printf("%s", root->varName);
                break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    

    // Print a tree using postorder traversal.
    void printTree(struct ParseNode* root)
    {
        int depth = treeDepth(root);

        printNode(root, depth, 1);
    }

    void freeTree(struct ParseNode *node)
    {
        if(node->left != NULL)
            freeTree(node->left);
        if(node->right != NULL)
            freeTree(node->right);

        node = NULL;
    }

    
%}


%union{
    int numValue;
    char stringValue[255];
    char charValue;
    struct ParseNode *node;
}


// I am sorry I was not able to finish this.  I would like to come in for help.
%token <node> NUM VAR EQUAL ADD SUB MUL DIV POW ENDL ERR

%type <node> assign exp term factor
//%type <node> assign exp

 
//%type <node> input assign exp term factor

%%

input:  /* nothing */
|   input exp ENDL      { printTree($2); freeTree($2); }
;

assign: VAR EQUAL exp   { $$ = createInstructionNode('=', $1, $3); }
;

exp:    term    { $$ = $1; }
|   exp ADD exp { $$ = createInstructionNode('+', $1, $3); }
|   exp SUB exp { $$ = createInstructionNode('-', $1, $3); }
;

term:   factor  { $$ = $1; }
|   term MUL term   { $$ = createInstructionNode('*', $1, $3); }
|   term DIV term   { $$ = createInstructionNode('/', $1, $3); }
|   term POW term   { $$ = createInstructionNode('^', $1, $3); }
;

factor: exp { $$ = $1; }
|   NUM { $$ = createValueNode($1->value, NULL, NULL); }
|   VAR { $$ = createVariableNode($1->varName, NULL, NULL); }
;

%%

int yyerror(const char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!yyin)
    {
        perror("File not found.");
        return 1;
    }

    do {
        yyparse();
    } while( !feof(yyin) );
    
    //yyparse();

    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}

And this is the makefile I use:
tp2: tp2.l tp2.y
    bison -d tp2.y
    flex tp2.l
    cc -o $@ tp2.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl

When I run it using ./a.out input.txt, it should try to read in the file line by line and print a parse tree.  Instead, it simply asks for my input on the command line.
I think this is an issue with trying to set yyin to read from a file.  Could anyone help me with this?

I do not reproduce the behavior you describe.  I haven't analyzed your grammar and parser to understand the language the program is supposed to read, but if I give it an existing, empty file as input, the program does not attempt to read input from the terminal.

Side note: you do not need to link libfl.  You're already providing your own versions of all the (very few) functions that libfl contains.  However, one of those is a main() that reads the standard input, so if somehow you're getting that instead of the main() you provide in tp2.y / tp2.tab.c, then that might explain your observation.  That shouldn't happen, but you can ensure that it doesn't by just not uselessly linking libfl.

freeTree() does nothing.  I'd expect node = NULL; to be free(node);.  I doubt this is OP's main issue.

Also, I don't think you're as close to done as you think you are. Pay attention to flex's and bison's diagnostics.  Bison reports several warnings about useless rules, and also reports tons of shift / reduce and reduce / reduce conflicts.  The latter are very bad -- each one probably means that your grammar is wrong.  The former are moderately bad -- some of them probably mean your grammar is wrong, but the default resolution of others might be what you want.  Even where the resolutions are what you want, however, you should try to clean up the ambiguities behind these conflicts.

@JohnBollinger I am using WSL to run Linux on Windows.  What are you using?

@ZacharyLund, I am using Linux, not that it makes a difference to anything I wrote.

Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal Bison grammar should normally have only a single production, unlike the much larger program presented here.

At least this error:
Wrong destination
strcpy(varName, node->varName); writes uninitialized data into varName.  Certainly OP wanted the copy the other way:
strcpy(node->varName, varName);

Better code would used a size limit like
if (snprintf(node->varName, sizeof node->varName, "%s", varName) >= sizeof node->varName){
  Handle_Error();  // Handle the error in some TBD fashion.
}

